# retrofit android - upload document using multi-part is throwing response code 422

Tags: android, upload, retrofit2, multipart

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public Response addAsset(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
    @FormDataParam("draftId") Long draftId) throws IOException
{
}
```

when used the chrome browser to look at the file upload request, it has the below in the "Form Data" section

------WebKitFormBoundaryaQvAp0c0jbhLq4af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="draftId"

------WebKitFormBoundaryaQvAp0c0jbhLq4af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryaQvAp0c0jbhLq4af--

does this mean the value of "draftId" is null ?

should i send "draftId" and "file" as multipart ?

the retrofit code i have tried in Android Studio is provided below

retrofit API for upload document request:

```
@POST("resource/asset")
@Multipart
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
fun uploadFile(

        @Part draftId: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): Call<ResponseBody>
```

the code that sends the upload request is below:

```
private fun uploadFile1(fileUri: Uri?) {
  file = com.example.myapplication.utils.FileUtils.getFile(mContext, fileUri)
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    val filePart: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse(activity!!.contentResolver.getType(fileUri!!)!!),
            file
    )

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file!!.name, filePart)
    val draft = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("draftId",null, draftpp)
    val call = apiInterface.uploadFile(draft, body)
    
         call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            Log.i("Upload", "success")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("Upload error:", t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

i am getting response code 422, can someone please help me fix the issue ?

Comment: `com.example.myapplication.utils.FileUtils.getFile()` probably is incorrect. A `Uri` is not a file. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) and [this blog post](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/) for instructions for how to post a multipart form body using a `Uri`.

Comment: when i passed  requestBody(for draftId) and multiPart(for file) for the API, it started working


val call = apiInterface.uploadFile(requestBody, bodyMultiPart)

Answer (score 0):

when i passed  requestBody(for draftId) and multiPart(for file) for the API, it started working

val call = apiInterface.uploadFile1(draftIddd, body )